# Dynamically Add Database Table Values to Drop-down List

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, zend-framework2

I have created custom plunging to get list of values from the database.

Now I want create a Drop-Down list using this array

This is my Select List

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'group_name',
    'type' => 'select',
    'attributes' => array(
        'id'=>'group_name',
        'class'=>'large',
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Select List',
        'value_options' => array(
            '1' => 'php',
            '2' => 'java'
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Even I am lazy to start from scratch :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not give all too much information about what it actually is, that you have trouble with, but for now I will assume that you have trouble to get Database Values into your Select elements. For this, please see detailed information on my Blog:

- [`Zend\Form\Element\Select` and Database Values](http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/)

The basic you need to understand is simple Depedency Injection. You will need to properly inject the Data-Sources (or the Data itself) into your Form. This is done using the `ServiceManager` of Zend Framework 2.

Since there are many different pathes one can choose (and even my Blog doesn't cover them all), i won't go into detail of any specific one until you request so. The Blog itself should be enough to get you started to be able to write a proper SO-Question ;)

Comment: Thanks Sam, This is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

What part of this is it you need help with? The HTML? The loop in PHP?
HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<select name="group_name">
  <option value="1">php</option>
  <option value="2">java</option>
</select>
</form>
```

The PHP, for the group_name:

```
echo $array['name'];
```

For the looping through the select values:

```
foreach($array['options']['value_options'] AS $key=>$option){
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$option.'</option>';
}
```

Something like this...???

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for the hardest thing
    `In Controller, add

```
$urFormObject->get('selectOptionName')->setValueOptions($listArray);
Example:
```

$formName->get('group_name')->setValueOptions($listArray);`